# How to deploy SSRS through App Proxy or Website

Tags: sql, azure, reporting-services, azure-active-directory

I'm having a very tough time getting this to work. We are using SSRS to view reports on our internal network. However, I would like to deploy SSRS so users from home can use it since we're working from home more frequently. I will supply a screenshot of the current config with the App Proxy settings and maybe you can point something out that I am doing wrong because I'm lost at this point and google has stopped helping.

At this moment, I am trying to deploy SSRS using App Proxy from Azure, however, if you know another way, please let me know.

Again, this is a simple deployment. We simply access SSRS using a http/s address internally and it works fine. I just want users to be able to use it from Home through a website.

[App Proxy Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gUZL2.png)
[App Proxy Cont.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i6epG.png)

Comment: Did you follow the docs here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/report-server/azure-application-proxy ?

Answer (score 0):

This ended up being a bit of a journey.

Do not install your AD Connect or App Proxy connectors on a Domain Controller. Put them on the same virtual server by themselves.

Set up your SQL Server and Oracle all under a domain service account. If you haven't done this already, get ready to reinstall because it's likely that manually switching the SPN keys isn't going to work.

Leave the default App Proxy settings alone when you Configure App Proxy.

If you have a weblink like reporting.domain.com/reports in Azure you MUST make sure you have reporting.domain.com/reports/ do not forget the extra / at the end.

App Proxy with SSRS will now work.

Use this as your overall guide

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/report-server/azure-application-proxy